# MonoTouch: CLLocationManagerDelegate UpdatedLocation

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

The UpdatedLocation in CLLocationManagerDelegate is now obsolete.

How would I get this functionality and under what new function call?

OLD:

```
        public override void UpdatedLocation (CLLocationManager manager, CLLocation newLocation, CLLocation oldLocation)
        {
            manager.StopUpdatingLocation ();
            locationManager = null;
            callback (newLocation);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with iOS 6, you have to override the `LocationsUpdated` method in your delegate:

```
public override void LocationsUpdated (CLLocationManager manager, CLLocation[] locations)
{
    // Code
}
```

The `locations` parameter will always contain at least one `CLLocation` object and the most recent location will be the last item in the array:

```
CLLocation recentLocation = locations[locations.Length - 1];
```

If your app supports iOS 5, you can keep the `UpdatedLocation` method. No other changes are needed, the same things apply when you call `StartUpdatingLocation` and `StopUpdatingLocation`.

This is explained in Apple's documentation on `CLLocationManager`'s `startUpdatingLocation` method [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startUpdatingLocation).